# US flag doesn't appear while changing the currency switcher to USD

Tags: frontend, currency

I have tried to update the currency switcher with respective flags. However during one of the session, i have uploaded the India flag as png file in the folder. Now when i change it to USD, the flag remains the same.

Comment: Need more details , try to update code.

Comment: Am bit new to magneto. Can you let me know the directory from which the code needs updation?

Comment: Magento1 or Magento2

Answer (score 0):

For ***Magento1*** ,

In the Rwd theme currency switcher path is

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/directory/currency.phtml

For ***Magento2*** ,
Default Luma theme, currency switcher path is

> vendor/magento/module-directory/view/frontend/templates/currency.phtml

Try to work on your custom theme,

M1 will be ,

> app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/template/directory/currency.phtml

M2 will be ,

> app/design/frontend/packagename/themename/Magento_Directory/templates/currency.phtml

let me know if works or face any issue.